# How do I find a Scheduled Job if I know its Job Name?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

There is a scheduled job by the name of Dispatch Jobs. Via Apex I want to check if that job is present. What would the syntax to do so?

Comment: Hi Joseph, going to mark this as a duplicate as it was asked and answered elsewhere, although the phrasing of the question was slightly difference which is likely why you didn't see it.

Comment: LaceySnr, thank you for pointing out the listing, it is what I was looking for.